# Execution date in the Kubernetes Job name created by CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

At the moment my daily Kubernetes CronJob creates job instances with a name with the following pattern:

```
my-chron-job-28038600-acddef
my-chron-job-28038660-acddef
my-chron-job-28038720-acddef
```

I was wondering, if there is an easy way to override this and ensure that the CronJob creates Job following a pattern like the following one, which includes the Job creation/execution date in a human readable format:

```
my-chron-job-2023-05-01-acddef
my-chron-job-2023-05-02-acddef
my-chron-job-2023-05-03-acddef
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible. However, you can use [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) to combine the pod name with the pod's start time:

```
kubectl get pods -l job-name -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.job-name}{"-"}{.status.startTime}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Note: the `job-name` label is automatically populated by k8s.

The output would be then something like:

```
my-chron-job-28052272-2023-05-11:52:00Z
...
```

You can further refine the output (through pipes, `awk`, `sed` etc.) to achieve exactly the desired format. I don't know if it'ld be worth the effort though.